# Slice notation - Reverse string excluding last character

Tags: python, string, slice

I am hoping to reverse a string 'str', and only keep the last character if a given number 'n' is even. My current method:

```
str[::-1][n%2:]
```

I am curious why the following does not produce the same result:

```
str[:-(n%2)-1:-1]
```

Comment: Does this work for you? str [: -((n%2)-1) : -1]

Comment: @Brijesh: your slicing yields 'noht'. Not the op the asker wants.

Comment: would be easier to help if you could include some input and desired output

Comment: @Mokshyam I am unable to replicate your solution. Could you share more.

Comment: @Brijesh Check with `str = 'python'; n=4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the slice `[start: end: step]`, you must ensure the **direction** of from `start` to `end` is same as the **sign** of `step`，it's means:

1. `start` < `end` if step is positive.
2. `start` > 'end' if step is negative.

> **Notice:**
>
> - -1 means the last item in the list.
> - `start` and `end` is decide by python when they are not specified.
> - `step` is default 1.

#### str[::-1]

`start` equals -1, `end` equals 0, `str[::-1]` produces a reserved list.

#### str[:-(n%2):-1]

`start` equals -1, `end` equals -0(n is even) or -1(n is odd).

- `end` equals -0, then `str[:-(n%2):-1]` produces a reserved list.
- `end` equal -1, then `str[:-(n%2):-1]` produces a empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Because in `str[:-(n%2)-1:-1]` (in the form str[x:y:z]) x and y are the starting and ending indices and z is the stride or how many characters you want to skip. By making z -1, the string is reversed; x must be greater than y so that the string extracted is not an empty substring. When you don't supply any value for x, it defaults to -1. So in fact your slicing is equivalent to `str[-1:-1:-1]` and so gives an empty string.

A little change to the slicing may yield the result you may want:

```
n=2
str[n%2-1:-len(str)-1:-1]
'nohtyp'
```

Of course if n is odd, this will give only 'p'. But I think you don't care.

Comment: When slicing using [start : stop : step], the way I have seen is that the ‘step’ function seems to act first and rearrange the string, and the index then starts the slicing function. Therefore in the second option, the minus-sign (as mentioned by @Mokshyam) will give you a empty string, as it does not exist. [Someone please correct me if I am wrong.]

“To keep the last character if a given number is even”, this would work.

k [::-1] [len(k)%2 :: -1]

Comment: @Brijesh `k [::-1] [len(k)%2 :: -1]` would miss the point of checking if n is even